# My Flex app sometimes take a time navigating away to another tab and back to load in browser

Tags: apache-flex

In my Flex app I give the user the ability to open up a new item form ( s:Panel ) and create multiple items on the page.

Sometimes for some odd reason bringing up the panel (simple task) seems to take a really long time to load (like 30 seconds or so) However, the weird thing is that if right after I click to open I navigate away from the Tab and back again to the Flex app tab it shows up right away.

I'm not sure if this has to do with refresh rate or some setting or is it general performance/memory issue with my app that I have to consider. When the application work it works fairly fast which is making me think it's not memory/performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without more details, but are you following the component life cycle? Just to be sure we're talking about the same thing, here's a nice presentation about it: http://www.slideshare.net/rjowen/adobe-flex-component-lifecycle-presentation

Comment: Thanks Robert. The presentation was actually useful I watched it all. However, I couldn't find what the relation between life cycle and switching windows/tabs

Comment: As I said it's hard to say anything from that description, I don't think it happens to anyone so it's probably something realted to your code. Maybe there's something happening in the backgroud that's taking a lot of CPU time?

Comment: Is there a way to check if something is holding the CPU. I have the Basic version of Flash Builder. Does the profiler in the Premium version offer that?

Comment: Looking at the system's CPU percentage, the behaviour is kind of weird. For the Flash Plugin-container the percentage of CPU is around 4-5% before loading something and it spikes right before the menu is or the item is loading but before that CPU is at low pecentage which tell me that it's likely not something that is holding the CPU but for some reason it's waiting for some time before it loads the menu (or it happens right away if I navigate away and back)..Any ideas?

Comment: I think it must be something specific to your code, but only you know it ;)

Comment: Thanks although there is no one answer for solving such problem the discuss helped guiding me to improving performance